# How to realize Virtual Inheritance in Go

Tags: go, virtual-inheritance

1. How to realize "Virtual Inheritance" in Go?
2. go lang compiler version: "1.3.1 windows/amd64", does it support "Virtual Inheritance" for Go?

I never heard a C like language could support "Virtual", so I really misunderstand.

Comment: Yes,the concept in c++.but I heard from someone that go can support it.I used to never heard about it.@nos

Comment: Boy, it's complicated. You can do the various things that folks use virtual inheritance in C++ for with [type embedding](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) (look for "anonymous types") and [interfaces](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) or a combination.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Virtual Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) solves [a problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) which does not exist if you don't have multiple inheritance. Consider the following inheritance tree:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

If classes B and C both provide a data-member (or method for that matter) with the same name then when accessing said member in D, you need a way to disambiguate whose ancestor's data-member (or method) you wish to access.

Virtual Inheritance is C++'s solution.

In Go you don't have inheritance to begin with; only composition and you can embed at most 1 member of any given type at once.

http://play.golang.org/p/1iYzdoFqIC

```
package main

type B struct {
}

func (b B) Foo() {}

type C struct {
}

func (c C) Foo() {}

type D struct {
    B
    C
}

func main() {
    d := D{B{}, C{}}
    // d.Foo() // <- ambiguous
    d.B.Foo()  // <- ok
    d.C.Foo()  // <- ok
}
```

Comment: Now I have better understanding about the concept of " Inheritance" and "Virtual Inheritance".And the same about go.Thanks very much.

Comment: Exactly... and this problems is only relevant for languages with [nominal sub-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system). Go is not an OO language, thus the problem virtual inheritance intends to solve is not relevant.

Comment: Virtual inheritance has zero to do with "disambiguation".

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Inheritance not only solves the problem of multiple inheritance but also gives us [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Form interface {
    Color() string
    Area() float64
}

type form struct {
    color string
}

func (f *form) Color() string {
    return f.color
}

type Circle struct {
    form
    radius float64
}

func (k *Circle) Area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * k.radius * k.radius
}

type Rectangle struct {
    form
    width, height float64
}

func (r *Rectangle) Area() float64 {
    return r.width * r.height
}

func main() {
    var forms [2]Form
    forms[0] = &Circle{
        form:   form{ "black" },
        radius: 5.0,
    }
    forms[1] = &Rectangle{
        form:   form{ "read" },
        width:  2.0,
        height: 3.0,
    }
    for _, f := range forms {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %.2f\n", f.Color(), f.Area())
    }
}
```

Here we have an array of things that have something in common (`Color` and `Area`) and we can just iterate over this array calling the same functions and always the right thing will happen.

This is just one advantage of polymorphism. It plays a big role in most [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Patterns_by_type).

Answer (score -1):

"Virtual Inheritance" is something more like this

http://play.golang.org/p/8RvPmB3Pof

```
package main

type A struct {
    virtual int
}

func (a *A) set(v int) {
     a.virtual = v
}

func (a *A) get() int {
    return a.virtual
}

type B struct {
    *A
}

type C struct {
    *A
}

type D struct {
    *B
    *C
}

func main() {
    a := &A{}
    b := &B{a}
    c := &C{a}
    d := &D{b, c}
    d.B.set(3)
    println(d.C.get())
    return
}
```